# 'Open'がインストールできません。

Tags: linux, ubuntu

環境はUbuntuです。'Open'コマンドをインストールしようとしたら以下のようにエラーが出ます。

```
sudo apt-get install open
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package open
```

ちなみに"Open"というコマンドを使ったら以下のように表示されます

```
Command 'Open' not found, did you mean:

  command 'open' from deb kbd
  command 'pen' from deb pen
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS には `/bin/open` というコマンドが存在していて、`kbd` パッケージに含まれています。

Comment: どうすれば、openを使えるようになりますか？

Comment: もしかして、これですかね。`Macは open test.txt や open test.png などとすれば対象のファイルをGUI上のアプリで開けますが、Ubuntuはxdg-openコマンドで同様のことができます。`  [Ubuntuの使い勝手をできるだけMacに近づける](https://qiita.com/akutius/items/e1b6b1c96f138c2823ed)

Comment: "open"ではなく"xdg-open"を使用すればいいということですか？

Comment: 紹介先のように、Macと類似の機能が欲しいならば、そういうことでしょう。紹介先の記事を良く読んでみてください。

Comment: @Can さん、`Open` という名前のコマンドにどういう挙動を期待していますか？　また、`Open` ですか `open` ですか？

Comment: 次の質問 [https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper でエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53138/26370) で詳細が明らかになったので、この質問自身は意味のなくなった質問として Close しても良いと思われます。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/177336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)の環境ですが、"Open"というパッケージは見つかりません。
インストールの前にまずは`apt search パッケージ名`で検索をしてみてください。

```
$ sudo apt search "open"
$ sudo apt search "^open$"
$ sudo apt search "^Open$"
```

以下のサイトで「完全に一致するもの」を条件に検索をした場合にも”Open"は存在しないようです。

[Ubuntu パッケージ検索](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: 最初のコマンドは多くのパッケージが表示されましたが、あとの二つはSorting... Done
Full Text Search... Doneと表示されました。

Comment: 1つ目の"open"は「openという文字が含まれる」パッケージ名を、2,3つ目は「openまたはOpenと完全に一致するもの」でパッケージ名をそれぞれ検索しています (結果が出ない = パッケージが無い)。

Comment: パッケージがないということは、ほかの方法があるということですか？