# https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper でエラー

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[やろうとしているアプリケーション](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper)
環境はWindows System for Linuxです。（PCはWindowsで、ubuntuをダウンロードして行っています。）
今Prerequisitesの４まで行ったのですが、４の

```
Open social_mapper.py and enter social media credentials into global variables at the top of the file
Command 'Open' not found, did you mean:

  command 'open' from deb kbd
  command 'pen' from deb pen

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

と表示され、できません。そして、

```
sudo apt-get instal openまたはkbd
E: Unable to locate package deb
```

とでます。
ここから、どうすればできますか？

Comment: その部分は「social_mapper.pyを開いて(または実行して)」であり、Openというコマンドを使うではないと思います。

Comment: @PicoSushiさん回答のように、元の資料が手作業についての説明を、コマンド入力のように記述しているのが誤解の元なのでしょう。`social_mapper.py` を **エディタで** 開いてというのがより分かりやすい記述でしょう。

Comment: エディタで開いたらusernameとpasswordを31から60行までのところに入力するんですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Open social_mapper.py and enter social media credentials into global variables at the top of the file`

とは、各種SNSの認証情報を `social_mapper.py` [上部の変数](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper/blob/726071510c060896bb7c4d77d3feb01a0deecc73/social_mapper.py#L30-L61)に入力する、という意味です。

このため、ユーザー名やパスワードをこの部分に入力してください。

Comment: vim social _mapper.pyと入力したら、次はこのhttps://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper/blob/726071510c060896bb7c4d77d3feb01a0deecc73/social_mapper.py#L30-L61 の31から60usernameとpasswordをすべて同じく入力すればいいんですか？

Comment: [記入したID/Passwordを利用している部分](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper/blob/726071510c060896bb7c4d77d3feb01a0deecc73/social_mapper.py#L1099-L1145)を確認するに、必要なものだけで良さそうです。