# エラーが出てできません: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, wsl

[行っているアプリケーション](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/social_mapper)
最後のpythonを実行したのですが、できません。どうすればできるようになりますか？（myhomeに写真が入っています。）

```
python social_mapper.py -f imagefolder -i /lan/social_mapper/myhome -m fast
-fb
＞Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "social_mapper.py", line 931, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(args.input):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lan/social_mapper/myhome/'
```

Comment: 質問のタイトルには、どのような質問なのか分かるようなタイトルにしてください。

Comment: PicoSushiさんの回答の通りだと思いますが、調査の方法もコメントさせて頂きます。ファイルの有り無しは「ls /lan/social_mapper/myhome」で確認可能です。このコマンドでファイル一覧が表示されず、Windows上で存在する場合ですが、WSLではWindows上の「c:\hoge」は「/mnt/c/hoge」にあたりますので、これに合わせて指定してみてください。

Comment: ls /lan/social_mapper/myhome
>-bash: cd: /mnt/c/Users/myhome: No such file or directory
と表示されました。しかし、cdしたらmyhomeまでいくことができます。これはどういうことですか？本当は存在しないということですか？

Comment: @Can さん、`myhome` という名前のフォルダは Windows の C ドライブ下にあるフォルダですか？

Comment: いいえ。もともとはCにあったのですが、/lan/social_mapperにmv移動しました。

Comment: @Can さん、`ls -lah /lan/social_mapper` の結果を質問文に追記して頂けませんか？　質問文下の「編集」から追記が可能です。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/177450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lan/social_mapper/myhome/'`

これは、 `'/lan/social_mapper/myhome/'` というディレクトリが存在しないというエラーです。

> myhomeに写真が入っています。

とのことですが、[これまでの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53138/https-github-com-spiderlabs-social-mapper-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)を確認するにWindows Subsystems for Linuxをお使いのようなので、おそらくWindowsではそのようなディレクトリがあるものの、Linux内部の環境では存在ないか、認識出来ていないではないでしょうか。

Comment: わかりました。新しい環境で試してみます。